# Concise way to run command if previous command completes successfully, when previous command is already running

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I use the following pattern often:

```
some_long_running_command && echo success
```

However, sometimes I forget to attach the `&& success`, so I write out the status check in the next line:

```
some_long_running_command
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo success
```

As you can see, the status check in the second example (`[ $? -eq 0 ] &&`) is much more verbose than the check from the first example (`&&`).

Is there a more concise way to run a command only if the previous command completes successfully, when the previous command is already running?

Comment: You cannot check the status of the last command while it is running. You can only print the exit status after it is finished. The shortest would be `echo $?`. Alternatively, a classic approach would be to modify your prompt to contain the exit status (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/bash-display-exit-status-in-prompt)). This way you always see the exit status of the last command.

Comment: @kvantour - maybe question was unclear. I am trying run a new command conditionally if the previous command that is already running completes successfully. I have edited the question to improve clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` exits its shell using the same exit status as the most recently completed command. This is true even if that command runs in the *parent* of the shell that executes `exit`: you can run `exit` in a subshell.

```
some_long_running_command
(exit) && echo success
```

Depending on the command, you can also suspend the job, then resume it with `fg`, which will have the same exit status as the command being resumed. This has the benefit of not having to wait for the command to complete before adding the new `&&` list.

```
some_long_running_command
# type ctrl-z here
fg && echo success
```

Generally, this will work as long as `some_long_running_command` doesn't have to keep track of some resource that is changing in real-time, so that you don't lose data that came and went while the job was (briefly) suspended.