# bash unable to delete files in array loop

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm using find to generate a list of old backups, compressed tars, into a file, then reading that file into while loop. I out put the list to a log and screen, both looking correct.

echo $x   works fine;
/vol4/backups/forms_02_24_2024.tar.gz

But "rm $x" doesn't work, because it's receiving changed line below;

rm: cannot remove '(arr+=(/vol4/backups/forms_02_24_2024.tar.gz))' :No such file or directory

```
arr()
while read line; do
   x="(arr+=("$line"))"
   echo $x
   rm $x
done < ./old_backups.txt
```

Tried using cut and sed to modify the line, but I still didn't get what rm needed, which is simply the path to each old file.  But rm is still no getting the correct file names.

Comment: `x` is just a string, not an array, so the `+=` is only a literal, not adding anything. Why can't you just `rm $line`?

Comment: The error message tells you where the problem lies. The path you are trying to remove is `(arr+=(/vol4/backups/forms_02_24_2024.tar.gz))`. Do you not realize that is from the third line of your program? Why do you even have a `arr()` array since yo¨don't use it? Just `rm "$line"`.

Comment: Does your version of `find` support `-delete`?

Comment: (look into `readarray` instead of a loop to populate an array with the lines of a file)

Comment: The output from the `echo` command you post here, does not fit the error message from the `rm` command. I don't believe that you posted this information correctly. Provide a screenshot of what happens when you run your script.

Comment: Wanted to thank OneCricketeer and Kurtis Rader for explaining my issue, that's helps me not do that again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the files listed in `old_backups.txt`:

```
xargs -t rm < ./old_backups.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a reason for wanting an array with the list of all the files that were deleted. If so, does this solve your problem:

```
arr=()
while read line; do
   arr+=($line)
   echo $line
   rm $line
done < ./old_backups.txt
echo "The following files were deleted: ${arr[*]}."
```

Obviously, the last line was more of an example of how you could use the arr array.

Answer (score -1):

Before `rm`, we can check for the file's existence. As a one-liner:

```bash
while read line; do [ -f ${line} ] && rm ${line}; done < ./old_backups.txt
```

Here, `[ -f ${line} ]` [check if file exists](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-check-if-file-exists/), and if and only if, the next instruction (`rm ${line}`) executes as enforced by [the `&&` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66013532/6519224).

Comment: The file itself already exists, it's shown in the echo display and log, the issue is that additional symbols are added once that file and path are fed to rm.  But thank you,

Comment: Yes, that worked like a charm, but any chance you can direct me to any white paper on why.  On first glance, the likes look identical, so I'm missing the way?  Thank you again, but if you don't mind, the why.

Comment: @user23562505, all did is add a simple `if` check on the file. Updated the answer with references. If you are a novice in shell scripting, [bash cookbook](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+cookbook&oq=bash+cook&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCggAEAAY4wIYgAQyCggAEAAY4wIYgAQyBwgBEC4YgAQyBwgCEAAYgAQyBggDEEUYOTIMCAQQABgUGIcCGIAEMgcIBRAAGIAEMgkIBhAAGAoYgAQyCAgHEAAYFhgeMggICBAAGBYYHjIICAkQABgWGB7SAQgyMTkyajBqMagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1) is a  great book. (Please mark the answer as accepted, if it helped)